# Connect to SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, database, codeigniter, sqlsrv

i want to connect to sql server 
my php version is 5.4 and i have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and i use PHP Codeigniger 2.4

i change database.php config

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '192.168.5.208';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

i download sqlsrv30.exe.
install it in php/ext

i add the following on the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

i install Native Client 10

i change sqlsrv_driver.php in folder database-driver-sqlsrv to

```
function db_pconnect() {
        //return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
        return $this->db_connect(TRUE);
    }
```

i also try add

```
db['default']['port'] = 1433;
```

but its still not working. I always encountered the ff. error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\HRM\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 124

what should i do ? please help

Answer (score 3):

this solves it

```
change  $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; to     $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

and

```
change $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; to $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: look i changed the my answer

Comment: thanks for your advise , finally i solve it , its just because sqlsrv require native client 11 but mine is 10, thank you

Comment: It worked for $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc'; as well. Thanks